# Manipulating infinite series

Tags: summation

If I type

```
Sum[f[x],{x,m,Infinity}]-Sum[f[x],{x,m+3,Infinity}]
```

I would like Mathematica to return something like

```
Sum[f[x],{x,m,m+2}]
```

or maybe

```
f[m]+f[m+1]+f[m+2]
```

But it doesn't seem to want to do this (maybe because it's worried that the difference makes no sense if the sums don't converge?).  Is there a simple way to let Mathematica know I would like it to make this kind of simplification?

Comment: A dirty way :`ClearAll[s];
s /: s[f[x], {x, a_, b_}] - s[f[x], {x, c_, b_}] := 
  s[f[x], {x, c + 1, a}];
simp[x_] := (x /. Sum -> s /. s -> Sum);
simp[Sum[f[x], {x, m + 3, Infinity}] - Sum[f[x], {x, m, Infinity}]]`

Comment: Don't you want `-Sum[f[x], {x, m, m+2}]` instead?

Comment: @RahulNarain:  Indeed.  I changed the example midway through posting and failed to change the second line.  Going back to fix this now.

Comment: I searched the DifferenceDelta and DiscreteShift, but I do not think it has anything to do with it.