# Series Manipulation

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

How do I get Mathematica to realize that it should simplify the expression

```
Sum[f[t],{t,1,Infinity}]-Sum[f[t],{t,2,Infinity}]
```

to

`f[1]` ?

Comment: But it shouldn't, because that's not true in general.

Comment: But I don't think *Mathematica* thinks about `Sum` as a formal series. Rather, it thinks of it as a sum of complex numbers, with the standard notion of convergence. The sums are left unevaluated because the `f[t]`s are unknown, but it is still interpreted as a sum of complex numbers. You will likely have to define your own rules, and perhaps your own `sum`, in order to make these kinds of simplifications occur.

Comment: Thanks.  This isn't the answer I'd hoped for, but it is informative.  I appreciate it.

Comment: But you can still implement your own `sum`!

Comment: Didn't you basically [already ask this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43247/manipulating-infinite-series) (with what seems like an answer in the comments)?

Comment: @march:  Yes, I know --- I'd have preferred to save this bit of work, but I'm already on it.

Comment: @march:  oh, my!  It seems that I did ask this question before, several months ago.  I had no memory of it, and even seeing the post is failing to jog my memory, but that's obviously my post.  Sorry for my absent-mindedness.